# How to get the id of the LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

here is my MainActivity sorry for the trouble

```
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
        // provider
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener 
            // to the button 
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main_widget);

            //Linear layout 
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);


            // Create an Intent to launch AppoinTextActivityClass from frontend 
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppoinTextActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonAT, pendingIntent);

            // Create an Intent to launch Day from frontend
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, RemindersToday.class);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pending); 

            // Create an Intent to launch Hours from frontend 
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, RemindersHour.class);
            PendingIntent pending1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pending1); 

            // Create an Intent to launch Customize from frontend
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, ReminderPeriodPicker.class);
            PendingIntent pending2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent3, 0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button3, pending2); 

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        } 
      } 
    }
```

Can someone please help me how do I get the id of linear layout and how to call an activity from the linear layout. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "call an activity from the linearlayout"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "calling an activity from linear layout", but for getting the id of the linear layout, in your onCreate, inflate the xml that you're using as the base layout of your app. something like

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout);
//be sure that you have defined View view as a global or inside your onCreate.
```

then call the linear layout like

```
LinearLayout ln = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout)
```

you need the view.findViewById to be able to reference the parent view in which your LinearLayout resides

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout)